# Point out the maker and speed of the laptops having hard drive capacity more or equal to 10 Gb

Tags: sql

I tried this in two ways (I think they are the same):

```
select product.maker,speed from product,laptop
where product.model=laptop.model and hd>='10'
```

and

```
select product.maker, speed from laptop
join product
on (product.model=laptop.model)
where hd>='10'
```

and I receive this in the simulator:

> "Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database. * Wrong number of records (more by 1)
>   This exercise has FAQ"

The relevant tables are:

#### Table Laptop

```
code    model   speed   ram hd      price       screen
------------------------------------------------------
1       1298    350     32  4.0     700.0000    11
2       1321    500     64  8.0     970.0000    12
3       1750    750     128 12.0    1200.0000   14
4       1298    600     64  10.0    1050.0000   15
5       1752    750     128 10.0    1150.0000   14
6       1298    450     64  10.0    950.0000    12
```

#### Table Product:

```
maker   model   Type
-----------------------
A       1232    PC
A       1233    PC
A       1276    Printer
A       1298    Laptop
A       1401    Printer
A       1408    Printer
A       1752    Laptop
B       1121    PC
B       1750    Laptop
C       1321    Laptop
D       1288    Printer
D       1433    Printer
E       1260    PC
E       1434    Printer
E       2112    PC
E       2113    PC
```

Comment: Do you get the same error on both or just the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select distinct product.maker, speed from laptop 
join product
on (product.model=laptop.model)
where hd>='10'

or

select distinct product.maker,speed from product,laptop 
where product.model=laptop.model and hd>='10'

Answer (score 3):

*When this answer was written, one query used `hd>=10` and one used `hd>='10'`. The query has since been edited.*

When you use the `'10'` in the comparison, you cause the DBMS to do the comparison as a string instead of as a number.  Under string comparison, `9` is greater than `10`.

As a general rule of thumb, if the data column is a string type, you should compare it with a string: if the column is numeric type, you should compare it with plain numbers (not with strings).  Note that different DBMS may have different ways of interpreting a mixed-type expression.

Comment: That's assuming that the `hd` column is itself a string. If it were any sensible numeric type, precedence should force the string to be converted appropriately. But I'd guess that you're correct here

Comment: I tried both ways with '10' and 10. They do the same thing. Please give me the correct query :).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It may depend on the DBMS, but some DBMS will take 'one side of a comparison is a string converts the other to a string'.  However, our OP has diligently changed the queries so they both use `hd>='10'`, so it is not clear that this answer applies, though why the string 10 is being compared with the HD size is anyone's guess.  Anybody seen a 10 GB laptop recently?

Comment: It's an exercise, are there other ways to produce the same result?

Comment: @Claudio as you can see from these comments it is necessary for you to mention the field types in your question to get a good answer. Please edit the question. And do not change the question based on the feedback. The entire StackOverflow issue becomes hard to understand for others if you do so.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't thought it would matter that much as it gave the same result. Stop talking of those silly quotes. The hd may be a number. Duh! ( I don't have that detail in the exercise) I said I tried both ways.

Comment: If you've got no further information for us, we have no further information that we can give you.  On the face of it, the two queries should give the same result.  If they don't, there is some crucial detail that we're missing.  One is the DBMS you're using; another is the types of each column in the schema; another is the significance of 'main database' and 'checking database' — and then there's the actual significant detail. Does the data you show correspond to the 'main' or the 'checking' database. Have you run the queries on your machine? Do they produce the same results?

Comment: "When this answer was written, one query used hd>=10 and one used hd>='10'. The query has since been edited." So yes, I tried both ways.

Comment: The queries do the same thing. I just stated that I tried those queries before asking the question on StackOverflow.

"Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database. * Wrong number of records (more by 1) This exercise has FAQ"

Comment: Hey @ClaudiuHaidu we don't know enough information about your homework database. I would highly recommend you specify that you want an `INNER JOIN` as maybe your homework DB is looking for that but beyond that I don't know what to tell you. Ask your teacher maybe. Also there people are trying to help you for free so maybe you should try to be a little more tactful or even better do your own homework.

Comment: Sorry, I overreacted.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem. I just had to use DISTINCT.

select distinct product.maker,speed from product,laptop
where product.model=laptop.model and hd>='10'

Answer (score 1):

```
Select P.maker, L.speed
from Laptop L, Product P
where P.model =L.model
And L.hd > = 10
Group by P.maker, L.speed
```

Try to use group by statement to get the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct Product.maker,Laptop.speed from Product,Laptop where Product.model=Laptop.model and Laptop.hd>=10 and type='laptop'

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT maker, speed 
from Product 
join Laptop on (Product.model=Laptop.model) 
where hd >= 10 
order by speed asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to filter for the laptops:

```
SELECT Product.maker, Laptop.speed
FROM Product INNER JOIN Laptop ON Laptop.model = Product.model
WHERE Laptop.hd >= 10 AND Product.type = 'Laptop'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `Distinct` before `product.maker`.